# Vuex mutator method unable to change state properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I have the following code in a vuex module named user.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
        user: {
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            lastLogin: null,
            email: null,
            password: null,
            token: null
        }
    },
    actions = {
        setUser({commit}, user){
            commit('setUser', user);
        }
    },
    mutations = {
        setUser:(state, newuser) => {
            console.log(newuser) // Point 1
            console.log(state.user) // Point 2
            state.user.firstName = newuser.firstName;
            state.user.lastName = newuser.lastName;
            state.user.lastLogin = newuser.lastLogin;
            state.user.email = newuser.email;
            state.user.password = newuser.password;
            state.user.token = newuser.token;
            console.log(state.user) // Point 3
        }
    },
    getters = {
        getUser: (state) => state.user
    };
export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
}
```

The console shows that the passed object at Point 1 has populated properties, but the `state.user.foo` lines between Point 2 and Point 3 do not properly assign those values to the state object declared above.

A console log from Point 3 shows the following:

```
{…}
email: (...)
firstName: (...)
lastLogin: (...)
lastName: (...)
password: (...)
token: (...)
```

How can I get this mutator to actually change the state?

Comment: can you do this in point 3: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.user)))` ? It's hard to read those `(...)`. Maybe they really have values

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw It returns an empty object ```{}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the direct assignments to `Vue.set(state, 'user', user)` causes the state to properly update.